# How to handle User Account Control window popup in desktop automation using winium

Tags: java, windows, automation, desktop-application, ui-automation

while running .exe file using winium it will launch a window popup(User Account Control window: - allow the application to make change) with all other apps minimized in the background, how to handle this kind of popups? Inspecting the window is not possible.

if I manually run the .exe file, the application will attach to the taskbar, to continue the operation I need to click on the icon in the taskbar, then only it will display username and password field.How to click on the icon in the taskbar?
how to create options for applications attached to the taskbar, which are already opened?

Comment: Automated handling UAC confirmation is not possible by OS design.

Comment: I was able to control UAC window popup by disabling it from computer settings, Thank for reply

Answer (score 0):

Go to

- Control panel
- user Account
- user Account control setting
- move to down (never notify)